# classic asp site randomly hangs IIS6

Tags: soap, asp-classic, iis-6

We have a classic ASP site that connects to a SOAP server.  We have not been able to figure out what causes the website to hang.  When we see that the website is hanging we simply restart the soap server and the website works fine(until the next time it hangs).  I want to mention that when the website hangs I can get to any page on the server that has .html or .htm extension, but any page that has an .asp extension will simply clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire up performance monitor, select Active Server Pages category and watch the Requests Executing counter.

You will likely see that over time this increases.  You have threads hanging waiting for incomplete calls to the SOAP Server.  Eventually ASP runs out of threads (usually 25 threads per CPU).  After that subsequent requests to ASP get queued waiting for a thread to come free, which it never does.