# My ASP local website randomly hangs. ASP pages unable to be loaded. But I can load HTML files just fine

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

My ASP local website randomly hangs. ASP pages unable to be loaded. But I can load HTML files just fine.

**IIS6 is used.**

See URL here: http://66.162.173.102/staff/asp/workspace/sos.asp

Above is an ASP page. Sometimes it loads but sometimes the browser keeps on waiting. Sometimes when you click on the link, it might load.

See an HTML page here: http://66.162.173.102/default/services.html

It loads just fine. Only ASP files are not served.

Attaching a part of the httperr.log file in C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

```
#Software: Microsoft HTTP API 1.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-04-27 15:00:09
#Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
2020-04-27 15:00:09 127.0.0.1 1166 127.0.0.1 80 HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS / 400 - Hostname -
2020-04-27 15:02:47 137.97.83.141 54553 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:10:56 81.30.144.119 63708 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/0.0 Invalid - 400 - Verb -
2020-04-27 15:11:24 137.97.83.141 54590 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:35:18 137.97.83.141 54699 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:35:18 137.97.83.141 54697 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:35:23 137.97.83.141 54698 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:46:19 192.168.1.58 56670 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:46:19 192.168.1.58 56671 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:46:19 192.168.1.58 56666 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:46:19 192.168.1.58 56672 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:46:19 192.168.1.58 56669 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:46:29 192.168.1.58 56674 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:54:35 99.170.175.52 54599 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 15:54:35 99.170.175.52 54646 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 16:09:33 99.170.175.52 56216 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-27 16:23:03 99.170.175.52 56215 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /staff/ASP/workspace/workspace.asp?category=&ClientID=&defaultjob=2 - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-27 16:55:34 99.170.175.52 60663 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /staff/ASP/workspace/neworder/new_job.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-27 16:57:04 99.170.175.52 60681 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /staff/ASP/workspace/neworder/new_job.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-27 17:00:34 99.170.175.52 60707 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /staff/ASP/workspace/neworder/new_job.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-27 17:02:34 99.170.175.52 61130 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /staff/ASP/workspace/neworder/new_job.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-27 17:17:33 99.170.175.52 61257 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /staff/ASP/workspace/neworder/new_job.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-27 17:50:20 189.176.60.218 41042 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / 400 - Hostname -
2020-04-27 18:58:47 189.115.113.249 48040 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / 400 - Hostname -
2020-04-27 19:16:04 54.81.225.190 33960 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /staff/ASP/workspace/current_transmittals_new.asp?JobNo=20-04-0300&FirstID=669711&ids=669711, - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-27 21:21:05 99.170.175.52 52333 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /staff/ASP/workspace/neworder/new_job.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-27 21:27:05 99.170.175.52 52788 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /staff/ASP/workspace/neworder/new_job.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-28 00:57:56 103.55.139.196 61000 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-28 01:00:41 23.100.232.233 16641 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /default/default.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-28 01:30:17 66.102.6.233 63969 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-28 01:30:17 66.102.6.235 59498 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-28 01:32:08 35.187.132.12 44364 192.168.1.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-04-28 01:34:11 23.100.232.233 20161 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /default/default.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2020-04-28 03:31:45 23.100.232.233 12609 192.168.1.100 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /default/default.asp - 1 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
```

The application is running on a Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition computer(SP2)

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I just restarted IIS service by going to IIS Manager. And the system came back online. I guess it is crossing some thread/process limits? So by restarting the IIS service, everything in queue gets cleared?

EDIT2: Below is my app pool configuration:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:microsoft-catalog:XML_Metabase_V64_0">
<MBProperty>
<IIS_Global Location ="."
        SessionKey="496353625000000034000000100000000b02000001680000016800009f5eaba7effed08c63e801021b182bbd43808d5113321a82615b9c6c27725f556db0dee91b179f1c69006e0055452cee47c54be335ff611ad70c622c"
    >
</IIS_Global>
<IIsApplicationPools    Location ="/LM/W3SVC/AppPools"
        AdminACL="49634462f0000000a40000004000000064aaed430304663d69e44bf2c8797f525f511bfae0d2c240eb0c25a2e6c3b3d60d1d9639f532969d01d0f77fd3e12e492ae947a0c910333d67eccfd0730449a5b692759f0537e105e1e55d88849a4e2df4c6485ed9790989643380c61b55a3708e3bb6a402aeb050909eb8f4e84cfad18eec3292bbaba7944f092623c8f885fb838b51cd2574205be47ee3a280c8c1597e220277635b06f8dc4146a2d74900c8df329d409beed66795d4d4af8fcd9e9cf9b3acdde6ff756a4dc64b26df45d13e40f513001800000049634862180000001000000000000000c28c1705293ef54d419bcfa4effb5070"
        AppPoolIdentityType="2"
        AppPoolQueueLength="4000"
        CPULimit="0"
        CPUResetInterval="5"
        DisallowOverlappingRotation="FALSE"
        DisallowRotationOnConfigChange="FALSE"
        IdleTimeout="20"
        LoadBalancerCapabilities="2"
        LogEventOnRecycle="AppPoolRecycleTime | AppPoolRecycleMemory | AppPoolRecyclePrivateMemory"
        MaxProcesses="1"
        OrphanWorkerProcess="FALSE"
        PeriodicRestartMemory="0"
        PeriodicRestartPrivateMemory="0"
        PeriodicRestartRequests="0"
        PeriodicRestartTime="1740"
        PingInterval="30"
        PingResponseTime="90"
        PingingEnabled="TRUE"
        RapidFailProtection="TRUE"
        RapidFailProtectionInterval="5"
        RapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes="5"
        SMPAffinitized="FALSE"
        SMPProcessorAffinityMask="4294967295"
        ShutdownTimeLimit="90"
        StartupTimeLimit="90"
    >
</IIsApplicationPools>
<IIsApplicationPool Location ="/LM/W3SVC/AppPools/DefaultAppPool"
        AppPoolAutoStart="TRUE"
        IdleTimeout="600"
    >
</IIsApplicationPool>
<IIsInheritedProperties Location ="inherited:/LM/W3SVC/AppPools"
        AccessFlags="AccessRead | AccessScript"
        AllowKeepAlive="TRUE"
        AnonymousUserName="IUSR_PLUTUS"
        AnonymousUserPass="4963446270000000220000004000000064aaed4320042cbdb6e46cf26a791a52725147fa98d2f440b00c04a287c382d60d1d00000100010045d9052509ef7a46bf20a4f9a0cc19d802000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000004c4d454d68000000f067e10100000000"
        AppAllowClientDebug="FALSE"
        AppAllowDebugging="FALSE"
        AppPoolId="DefaultAppPool"
        AspAllowOutOfProcComponents="TRUE"
        AspAllowSessionState="TRUE"
        AspAppServiceFlags="0"
        AspBufferingLimit="4194304"
        AspBufferingOn="TRUE"
        AspCalcLineNumber="TRUE"
        AspCodepage="0"
        AspDiskTemplateCacheDirectory="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\ASP Compiled Templates"
        AspEnableApplicationRestart="TRUE"
        AspEnableAspHtmlFallback="FALSE"
        AspEnableChunkedEncoding="TRUE"
        AspEnableParentPaths="FALSE"
        AspEnableTypelibCache="TRUE"
        AspErrorsToNTLog="FALSE"
        AspExceptionCatchEnable="TRUE"
        AspExecuteInMTA="0"
        AspKeepSessionIDSecure="0"
        AspLCID="2048"
        AspLogErrorRequests="TRUE"
        AspMaxDiskTemplateCacheFiles="2000"
        AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed="4000000"
        AspProcessorThreadMax="25"
        AspQueueConnectionTestTime="3"
        AspQueueTimeout="4294967295"
        AspRequestQueueMax="3000"
        AspRunOnEndAnonymously="TRUE"
        AspScriptEngineCacheMax="250"
        AspScriptErrorMessage="An error occurred on the server when processing the URL.  Please contact the system administrator."
        AspScriptErrorSentToBrowser="TRUE"
        AspScriptFileCacheSize="500"
        AspScriptLanguage="VBScript"
        AspScriptTimeout="200"
        AspSessionMax="4294967295"
        AspSessionTimeout="600"
        AspTrackThreadingModel="FALSE"
        AuthChangeURL="/iisadmpwd/achg.asp"
        AuthExpiredURL="/iisadmpwd/aexp.asp"
        AuthExpiredUnsecureURL="/iisadmpwd/aexp3.asp"
        AuthFlags="AuthAnonymous | AuthNTLM"
        AuthNotifyPwdExpURL="/iisadmpwd/anot.asp"
        AuthNotifyPwdExpUnsecureURL="/iisadmpwd/anot3.asp"
        CGITimeout="300"
        CacheISAPI="TRUE"
        ConnectionTimeout="120"
        ContentIndexed="TRUE"
        DefaultDoc="Default.htm,Default.asp,index.htm,Default.aspx,index.php"
        DirBrowseFlags="DirBrowseShowDate | DirBrowseShowTime | DirBrowseShowSize | DirBrowseShowExtension | DirBrowseShowLongDate | EnableDefaultDoc"
        DownlevelAdminInstance="1"
        HttpCustomHeaders="X-Powered-By: ASP.NET"
        HttpErrors="400,*,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\400.htm
            401,1,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\401-1.htm
            401,2,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\401-2.htm
            401,3,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\401-3.htm
            401,4,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\401-4.htm
            401,5,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\401-5.htm
            401,7,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\401-1.htm
            403,1,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-1.htm
            403,2,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-2.htm
            403,3,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-3.htm
            403,4,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-4.htm
            403,5,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-5.htm
            403,6,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-6.htm
            403,7,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-7.htm
            403,8,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-8.htm
            403,9,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-9.htm
            403,10,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-10.htm
            403,11,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-11.htm
            403,12,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-12.htm
            403,13,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-13.htm
            403,15,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-15.htm
            403,16,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-16.htm
            403,17,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-17.htm
            403,18,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403.htm
            403,19,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403.htm
            403,20,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\403-20.htm
            404,*,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\404b.htm
            404,2,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\404b.htm
            404,3,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\404b.htm
            405,*,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\405.htm
            406,*,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\406.htm
            407,*,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\407.htm
            412,*,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\412.htm
            414,*,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\414.htm
            415,*,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\415.htm
            500,12,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\500-12.htm
            500,13,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\500-13.htm
            500,15,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\500-15.htm
            500,16,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\500.htm
            500,17,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\500.htm
            500,18,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\500.htm
            500,19,FILE,C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\500.htm"
        InProcessIsapiApps="C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpext.dll
            C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpodbc.dll
            C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll
            C:\WINDOWS\system32\msw3prt.dll
            C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
            C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
        LogExtFileFlags="LogExtFileDate | LogExtFileTime | LogExtFileClientIp | LogExtFileUserName | LogExtFileServerIp | LogExtFileMethod | LogExtFileUriStem | LogExtFileUriQuery | LogExtFileHttpStatus | LogExtFileWin32Status | LogExtFileServerPort | LogExtFileUserAgent | LogExtFileHttpSubStatus"
        LogFileDirectory="C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles"
        LogFilePeriod="1"
        LogFileTruncateSize="20971520"
        LogOdbcDataSource="HTTPLOG"
        LogOdbcPassword="4963446260000000120000004000000064aaed43710410bd85e427f2377918525f516f006c0075006d00650031005c00570049004e0044004f00570053005c00730079007300740065006d00330032005c006d006d0063002e0065007800650000009cf400000000"
        LogOdbcTableName="InternetLog"
        LogOdbcUserName="InternetAdmin"
        LogPluginClsid="{FF160663-DE82-11CF-BC0A-00AA006111E0}"
        LogType="1"
        MaxBandwidth="4294967295"
        MaxConnections="4294967295"
        MinFileBytesPerSec="240"
        PasswordChangeFlags="AuthChangeDisable | AuthAdvNotifyDisable"
        ScriptMaps=".asa,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
            .asax,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .ascx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .ashx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .asmx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .asp,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
            .aspx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .axd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .cdx,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
            .cer,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
            .config,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .cs,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .csproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .idc,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpodbc.dll,5,GET,POST
            .licx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .php,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST
            .rem,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .resources,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .resx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .shtm,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST
            .shtml,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST
            .soap,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .stm,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST
            .vb,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .vbproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .vsdisco,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
            .webinfo,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"
        UNCPassword="4963446250000000060000004000000064aaed4302040000000000006f0074000000640065006600610075006c0074000000630072006f006e005f007300650072007600650072002e00610073007000000061488124324b"
        WAMUserName="IWAM_PLUTUS"
        WAMUserPass="4963446270000000220000004000000064aaed4348041dbda3e400f26179175278512efaa3d29e40ac0c2ca28dc3fdd60d1d00000100010045d9052509ef7a46bf20a4f9a0cc19d802000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000004c4d454d68000000f067e10100000000"
    >
</IIsInheritedProperties>
</MBProperty>
</configuration>
```

EDIT3: I guess it has something to with CPU usage. Is it because of process still not recycled?
[image: CPU usage]

Comment: Check your Application Pool settings for the site in IIS.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on which option in the settings you are referring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classic ASP site is hanging occasionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624835/classic-asp-site-is-hanging-occasionally)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [classic asp site randomly hangs IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7289575)

Comment: The first one is not my case, I tried the second one, the counters mentioned are not displaying for me.

Comment: See EDIT 2 above.

Comment: if you replace content of sos.asp to just `<%=now%>` will it make any difference? I mean we don't know what your asp site is doing, perhaps it hangs due to the code.

Comment: @user2316116, no it makes no difference. see snapshot of performance monitor window in EDIT3.

Comment: Anyone know an answer?